# Не срабатывает обработчик ошибки 404. Приложение Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mvc, spring-mvc

Разрабатываю сайт на Spring. Если перейти по бессмысленному url, то ожидаемо получаем ошибку 404:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Aug 08 19:58:48 MSK 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Я хочу обработать эту ошибку, что бы вместо этого сообщения появлялась страница  error404.html. Для этого написан вот такой код:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleNotFoundError() {
        System.out.println("Ошибка 404!");
        return "error404";
    }
}
```

Однако, страница error404.html не загружается и в консоль сообщение "Ошибка 404!" не выводится. Почему это происходит?

P.S. error404.html лежит там же где остальные temlates файлы. Также, в файле application.properties указал:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Помимо строки

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

в `.properties`-файл надо также добавить строку

```
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Итого получится:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Если версия Spring-а новая (сравнительно новая), то такое решение должно сработать.